# Adding tags to header with rpmlib

Tags: c, rpm

I am trying to create a new header and insert some tags with the RPM [Header API](http://rpm.org/api/4.12.0.1/group__header.html) using the [headerPut*](http://rpm.org/api/4.12.0.1/group__header.html#ga9a7cc53243734db48200933aecaea57c) functions, but in this simple example my attempted insertions fail with the exception of `headerPutString` and I am at a loss as to why:

```
Header s = NULL;
unsigned char md5[16] = {0};
uint32_t size = 42;

s = headerNew();

if (headerPutString(s, RPMSIGTAG_SHA1, "foo") != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "headerPutString error\n");

if (headerPutUint32(s, RPMSIGTAG_SIZE, &size, 1) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "headerPutUint32 error\n");

if (headerPutBin(s, RPMSIGTAG_MD5, md5, 16) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "headerPutBin error\n");
```

Running this outputs:

```
headerPutUint32 error
headerPutBin error
```

and when I then call `headerWrite` and examine the resulting file contents with the `hexdump` tool, I can see that the header only contains the string-type tag.

Why can't I insert the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some `gdb` debugging and looking through [the RPM source files](https://github.com/Tojaj/rpm/blob/master/lib/headerutil.c), I see where the problem is.

In the signature, `RPMSIGTAG_SIZE` (1000) is of type `INT32` and `RPMSIGTAG_MD5` (1004) is of type `BIN`. The problem is that these symbolic values also correspond to RPM header tags, where the type differs: `RPMTAG_NAME` is 1000 and is a `STRING`, `RPMTAG_SUMMARY` is 1004 and is an `I18NSTRING`. The RPM source files have no way to distinguish between the two and assume they are header tags, not signature tags.

Fortunately, the API also contains the [`headerPut`](http://rpm.org/api/4.12.0.1/group__header.html#ga2275b05ca8482917028356781f9a125d) function. This is actually what gets called by the type-specific functions after the sanity checks (including type checking), `headerPut` itself doesn't attempt any tag-type match, it just goes ahead and tries to add/append it, and is therefore a good solution for these situations.